# Fille Chooser unable to select csv, xlsx file Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, opencsv

I am learning Android App Development and trying to make an app which selects a csv or excel file and then parse the data into a Recycler View.
Here I am using a csv file:

```
Name, Price
Item1, 10
Item2, 20
Item3, 30
```

but when click the upload button the file chooser opens successfully but its not showing any csv or xlsx file present in the device although file is present.

Here is the code :

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdminHome extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button logOutBtn, uploadBtn;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView tvEmail;
    private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 1;
    private List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_home);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
        logOutBtn = findViewById(R.id.logOutBtn);
        uploadBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);
        String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        tvEmail.setText(email);


        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        logOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signOut();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*"); // Allow all file types
        String[] mimeTypes = {"text/csv"}; // Add CSV MIME type
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String path = uri.getPath();
                try {
                    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path));
                    String[] line;

                    while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                        String name = line[0];
                        String price = line[1];
                        menuItemList.add(new MenuItem(name, price));

                    }
                    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
                    MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(menuItemList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                    reader.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finishAffinity();
    }

    public void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(AdminHome.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

[image: As you can see I have a csv file present but its not getting selected]

As you can see in the image the resto.csv file cannot be selected but i want it to be selected so that the data can be parsed.
***THERE ARE NO ERRORS so i think there must be some logical error***
I tried to remove these lines thinking that it will allow all types of files to select which it did but then it was not parsing the data:

```
        String[] mimeTypes = {"text/csv"}; // Add CSV MIME type
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);`
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: `String[] mimeTypes = {"text/csv` Remove that. Just `*/*` will show all files.

Comment: @AlexMamo As you can see in the image the resto.csv file cannot be selected but i want it to be selected so that the data can be parsed.
THERE ARE NO ERRORS so i think there must be some logical error

Comment: @blackapps tried that too but doesnt help...